# Simple radio form utilizing localStorage not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, forms, local-storage

I have a simple PHP form with radio button input. I have included a script to remember selections using localStorage, and a script with button to clear the radio selections. I also have a script that checks to confirm that localStorage is available on the browser. On my full PHP page, I have other functions and processes. I am only including the problematic section.

The form works perfectly cross-browser on the desktop - button values retain checked values upon reposting. It will retain values in that browser the next time you go to the form, even after you close and reopen the browser at a later date - that is, until you clear the localStorage radio selection values by clicking on the "Reset Form" button.

But, this does not work on IOS (iPhone 5s) - the button selections are not retained, even though localStorage is available on the browser (Safari).

Here is the code - I kept the vanilla html to a minimum (for simplicity):

radio.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<title>Test Form for Sticky Mobile Radios</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Test Form for Sticky Mobile Radios</h2><br />
<form name="radio-test" action="" method="post"><br />
<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio"><label for="radio1" class="radio">Radio 1</label>
<input id="radio2" type="radio" name="radio"><label for="radio2" class="radio">Radio 2</label>
<input id="radio3" type="radio" name="radio"><label for="radio3" class="radio">Radio 3</label><br />
<input id="radio4" type="radio" name="radio2"><label for="radio4" class="radio">Radio 4</label>
<input id="radio5" type="radio" name="radio2"><label for="radio5" class="radio">Radio 5</label>
<input id="radio6" type="radio" name="radio2"><label for="radio6" class="radio">Radio 6</label><br />
<input id="radio7" type="radio" name="radio3"><label for="radio7" class="radio">Radio 7</label>
<input id="radio8" type="radio" name="radio3"><label for="radio8" class="radio">Radio 8</label>
<input id="radio9" type="radio" name="radio3"><label for="radio9" class="radio">Radio 9</label><br />
<input name="radio_test" type="submit" />
<br />

<button id="myBtn" name="myName" onclick="reloadpage();">Reset Form</button><br />
<div id="status">Local Storage is </div>

<script>
// Test if localStorage is available
function lsTest(){ 
    var test = 'test';
    try {
      localStorage.setItem(test, test);
      localStorage.removeItem(test);
      return true;
    } catch(e) {
      return false;
    }
}

var elem = document.getElementById('status');

if(lsTest() === true){
    elem.innerHTML += 'available.';
}else{
    elem.innerHTML += 'unavailable.';   
}

// This will use localstorage to retain radios checked:
$(function()
{
    $('input[type=radio]').each(function()
    {
        var state = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('radio_'  + this.id) );

        if (state) this.checked = state.checked;
    });
});

$(window).bind('unload', function()
{
    $('input[type=radio]').each(function()
    {
        localStorage.setItem(
            'radio_' + this.id, JSON.stringify({checked: this.checked})
        );
    });
});

// This will uncheck radios
function reloadpage(){
    var x = document.getElementById("myBtn").name;
    $(function uncheckradios()
{
    $('input[type=radio]').each(function()
    {
        var state = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('radio_'  + this.id) );

        if (state) this.checked = state.checked;
    });
});

$(window).bind('unload', function()
{
    $('input[type=radio]').each(function()
    {
        localStorage.setItem(
            'radio_' + this.id, JSON.stringify({checked: this.unchecked})
        );
   });
});
    location.href = location.href;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I tested the iphone and confirmed that it does have localStorage, yet the script does not retain the radio values. 
Can anyone help - I have tried numerous things with no solution. My last attempt was to add the Security Policy meta tag (I know it's a long one ...):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src * 'self' data:; default-src * 'self' gap: ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; ">
```

Still no success... On desktop and tablet it is fine, but on the iPhone it does not retain values.

Others might have a similar issue - can anyone help?

Thank you for your consideration and advice!

Comment: Are you testing this in incognito mode in iPhone?

Comment: no - iPhone in regular mode.I have tried this using several browsers on the phone (Chrome, Safari, Firefox) - not working on any of them. But, it does work cross-browser on desktop and tablets... Thank you for asking, and my apologies for not clarifying up front on this.

Comment: Safari in regular browsing mode (not Private)

Comment: To make this easier - please see the DEMO page here:
    http://consultapedia.com/radio.php